# How to get the value of the selected checkbox in visualforce page and pass it to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, inputcheckboxes

I have a requirement where i have to pass the value of the selected check boxes to controller method.

[image]

i need to send the combination of values, i.e Auditoriums and Carpet to my controller. Can you please help here.

```
<apex:page standardController="Deal__c" extensions="RoomAndFloorTypesController" sidebar="false">
    <apex:form >

    <apex:includeScript value="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js" />

    <apex:commandButton value="Proceed with Selected" action="{!ProceedWithSelected}" reRender="panelId"/>
    <apex:pageBlock id="pageBlockId" >
        <apex:outputPanel id="panelId">
            <apex:pageblockTable value="{!wrapperList}" var="wrapRec" rendered="{!normalList}">
             <apex:column>
                 <apex:inputCheckbox id="val" value="{!wrapRec.selected}" onclick="callRoomType('Auditoriums');"/>
              </apex:column>
              <apex:column value="{!wrapRec.opp}"/>
            <apex:column >

                   <apex:selectList value="{!selected}" size="1" label="Account">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklst}"></apex:selectOptions>
                  </apex:selectList>     

               </apex:column>                     
           </apex:pageblockTable>



               <apex:pageblockTable value="{!selectedWrapperList}" var="wrapRec" rendered="{!selectedList}">

                   <apex:column value="{!wrapRec.opp}"/>
                   <apex:column >
                       <apex:inputCheckbox value="{!wrapRec.selected}"/>
                   </apex:column>
              </apex:pageblockTable>
            </apex:outputPanel>      
        </apex:pageBlock> 
        <apex:actionFunction action="{!sendRoomType}" name="sendRoomType" />
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function callRoomType(checkbox){
        alert('hi ='+document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id1:pageBlockId:j_id3:5:cb1").value);
        sendRoomType(room);

        }


        </script>

        <script>

            $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#callRoomType').change(function() {
            if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
                alert("You have elected to show your checkout history."); //checked
            }
            else {
                alert("You have elected to turn off checkout history."); //not checked
            }
        });
    });

        </script>

    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

**Controller Class :**

```
public class RoomAndFloorTypesController{

    public string selected{get;set;}

    List<SelectOption> valuesfrompicklist{get;set;}
    public RoomAndFloorTypesController(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){
        normalList = true;
        selectedList = false;
        fetchData();

    }
    public boolean normalList{get;set;}
    public boolean selectedList{get;set;}
    public Prodrate_Rooms__c prodRateObj{get;set;}

    public void fetchData(){
       List<Prodrate_Rooms__c > allOpps = [Select name,Id, Room__c, Flooring__c from Prodrate_Rooms__c];

        Set<string> parentIdSet = new Set<String>();
        //Create parent Id set 
        for(Prodrate_Rooms__c OppertunityRec :allOpps){
            parentIdSet.add(OppertunityRec.Room__c);
            system.debug('parentIdSet=='+parentIdSet);
        }

        wrapperList = new list<myWrapperClass>();
        //For loop to set data
        for(String childRec : parentIdSet){

            //Adding Opportunities without account
            if(childRec != null){
                    myWrapperClass wrapRec = new myWrapperClass();

                    wrapRec.opp = childRec;
                    wrapperList.add(wrapRec);

            }

        } 
    }
    public List<myWrapperClass> selectedWrapperList {get; set;}
    public void ProceedWithSelected(){
        selectedWrapperList = new List<myWrapperClass>();
        normalList = false;
        selectedList = true;
        for(myWrapperClass selectedWrapObj: wrapperList){
            system.debug('selectedWrapObj.selected  ---------'+selectedWrapObj.selected);
            if(selectedWrapObj.selected == true)
            selectedWrapperList.add(selectedWrapObj);
        }
        system.debug('selectedWrapperList size ---------'+selectedWrapperList.size());
    }

    //Wrapper list 
    public List<myWrapperClass> wrapperList {get; set;}
    //Your wrapper 
    public class myWrapperClass{

        public String opp{get;set;}
        public Boolean selected {get; set;} 
        public myWrapperClass() { 
            selected = false; 
        } 
    }

    public List<SelectOption> getpicklst(){
        List<SelectOption> option=new List<SelectOption>();
        List<Prodrate_Rooms__c> acclst=[Select id,Room__c,Flooring__c from Prodrate_Rooms__c where Room__c='Auditoriums'];
        system.debug('acclst=='+acclst);


        for(Prodrate_Rooms__c ob:acclst){
            system.debug('ob=='+ob);
            option.add(new SelectOption(ob.id,ob.Flooring__c));
            system.debug('option inside loop=='+option);
        }
        return option;
    }

    public void sendRoomType(){
        system.debug('RoomType==');
        getpicklst();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Create one more string variable in your wrapper class and bind that with your select List

```
public class myWrapperClass{

    public String opp{get;set;}
    public String selectedvalue{get;set;}
    public Boolean selected {get; set;} 
    public myWrapperClass() { 
         selected = false; 
      } 
}
```

Now update your selectList

```
<apex:selectList value="{!wrapRec.selectedvalue}" size="1" label="Account">
     <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklst}"></apex:selectOptions>
</apex:selectList>
```

Now you will get both value

```
for(myWrapperClass selectedWrapObj: wrapperList){
    system.debug('selectedWrapObj.selected  ---------'+selectedWrapObj.selectedvalue);
    if(selectedWrapObj.selected == true)
           selectedWrapperList.add(selectedWrapObj);
}
```

Currently you are binding it with single variable thats why you don't get correct value.

Comment: Thans for your reply. My requirement is to pass the value : Auditorium and Carpet. This combination of data should be saved and sent to next page based on which calculations will take place.  i need to get the value dynamically of the checkbox  and send to controller. As of now i am hardcoding. Please check below code :  `<apex:column >
                  
                   <apex:selectList value="{!selected}">
                   <apex:selectOptions value="{!picklst}"></apex:selectOptions>
                  </apex:selectList>     
                    </apex:column>`

Comment: `and then calling a javascript function 
        `function callRoomType(checkbox){    alert('hi'+document.getElementById("j_id0:j_id1:pageBlockId:j_id3:5:cb1").value);
    sendRoomType(rooom)}``

Comment: `<apex:column>
                 <apex:inputCheckbox id="val" value="{!wrapRec.selected}" onclick="callRoomType('Auditoriums');"/>
              </apex:column>`

Comment: @user47646 Did you read my answer? check my last for loop there you will get all selected value with related picklist value as well.